# Update namedStyles through Google Docs API

Tags: google-docs-api

I am trying to update the **namedStyles** through Docs API, but struggling to find a way around it. It seems you can only create namedStyles when creating a new document through the API - batchUpdate doesn't seem to want to touch it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could notice that I misunderstood "namedStyles" and "namedRange". I deeply apologize for this. From this, I could understand that my answer is required to be deleted because it is not related to your goal. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: About managing "namedStyles", unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for achieving this. This is the current answer for your question. But Docs API is growing now. So it might be added in the future update. But, I think that you can also report this to the issue tracker as the future request. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) When I searched this, unfortunately, I couldn't find about this.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, and no problem at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As Tanaike said in a comment, currently **namedStyles** cannot be updated via Docs API, even though this action can be done through Docs UI. There is currently no possible [batchUpdate request](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request) to achieve this via API.

You could consider filing a Feature Request in [this Issue Tracker component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/555502#basic).

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AndrasSztrokay you're welcome. Please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you consider it helpful. This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.